# How return completable on room transaction Android

Tags: android, kotlin, android-room, android-architecture-components

I need your help please.

I have dao interface that save some configurations:

```
@Dao interface ConfigDao {
    @Insert(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun insert(config: Config)

    @Update(onConflict = OnConflictStrategy.REPLACE)
    fun update(config: Config)

    @Query("select * from T_CONFIG where isSelected = :isSelected")
    fun getConfig(isSelected: Boolean): Single<Config>

    @Query("select * from t_config")
    fun getConfigAll(): LiveData<MutableList<Config>>

    @Query("update T_CONFIG set isSelected = :isSelected where idEnvironment = :id")
    fun updateConfigById(id: String, isSelected: Boolean):Completable

    @Transaction
    fun updateConfigTransaction(configSelected: Config){

        if (configSelected.idEnvironment == Environtment.Type.PRD.toString()){
            updateConfigById(Environtment.Type.PRD.toString(), false)
            updateConfigById(Environtment.Type.DEV.toString(), true)
        }else{
            updateConfigById(Environtment.Type.PRD.toString(), true)
            updateConfigById(Environtment.Type.DEV.toString(), false)
        }
    }
}
```

I need to know when the transaction is complete with success or error.
I tried to implement `Completable` from `io.reactivex` but it's not possible.

Answer (score 3):

#### Since Room 2.1.0

> **Additional Async Support:** DAO methods annotated with `@Insert`, `@Delete` or `@Update`, along with `@Query` containing `INSERT`, `DELETE` or `UPDATE` statements, now support Rx return types `Completable`, `Single`, `Maybe`, and Guava's return type `ListenableFuture`, and they can also be suspend functions.

Source: https://developer.android.com/jetpack/androidx/releases/room#2.1.0

#### Older versions

Change the interface to an abstract class. You'll have to prefix all methods without implementation with `abstract`. Then:

```
abstract class ConfigDao(private val db: MyDatabase) {

    private val scheduler = Schedulers.from(db.queryExecutor)

    // Make sure the method is open so Room can generate the transaction handling code.
    @Transaction
    open fun updateConfigTransaction(configSelected: Config){
        // ...
    }

    fun updateConfigTransactionAsync(configSelected: config): Completable {
        return Completable
            .fromAction { updateConfigTransaction(config) }
            .subscribeOn(scheduler)
    }
}
```

`subscribeOn(db.queryExecutor)` makes sure the query runs on the same thread as all other DAO methods returning RxJava types. Replace `MyDatabase` constructor parameter with whatever your database class is.

Comment: `subscribeOn(db.queryExecutor)` gives me a compile error. Did you set a specific executor in your database setup or something?

Comment: Do you mind quoting the error so I have an idea what's happening? There's a `RoomDatabase.getQueryExecutor()` method. `Did you set a specific executor in your database setup or something?` I didn't but if I did I wouldn't want to track it manually. That's why I ask my database to give me its query executor. The default is `ArchTaskExecutor.getIOThreadExecutor()` but I don't care - I ask the database for the correct answer.

Comment: It was a type mismatch. Expected Scheduler, got Executor. What is the advantage of specifying an executor? This is the only place I've seen it

Comment: You're right, my mistake, just fixed it. You may need to specify custom DB executor for unit testing, I think that's the main point why the API is there.